# Debugging code that is run in node.js's vm

Tags: node.js

I am having the following issue - I am attempting to debug/set a breakpoint in code that is run using the vm module. The only way that I have found to accomplish this is by putting a debugger statement:

```
// client code, loaded in the vm module
function printMessage() {
    debugger;
    return 56;
}

printMessage();
```

Is there any other way to accomplish this? Preferably using tools such as node-inspector?

EDIT: Found a solution - by passing a string for "filename" to the executing function from vm. For example:

`vm.runInThisContext(codeToRun, "someFilename.js");`

this way the debugger "figures out" where exactly the code came from.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, `node-inspector` is a good candidate for this task. Can't you just start `node-debug someFilename.js` and set your breakpoints directly in the UI ?

Another alternative is to use `debugger` with and then run `node debug someFilename.js` and use commands like `setBreakpoint('someFilename.js', 10)`

You can find more information in the node documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html